# change asp.net mvc2 site culture (Model Validation Fails with Non-US Dates)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, localization, internationalization, culture

I have an asp.net mvc2 app that issue Validation errors on Europe style dates (dd/mm/yyyy)

I've found that the CurrentUICulture is en-us.
how can I change it permanently and to all the app to be like in Europe (en-GB ?)

Do I need to change something on the Database as well (SQL server 2008, default installation).

(this issue is linked to [ASP.NET MVC2 Model Validation Fails with Non-US Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851758/asp-net-mvc2-model-validation-fails-with-non-us-date-format) question)

But I don't want to treat dates all over the app, rather having the app work entirely in the right culture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like changing the server culture (in regional settings) solve it for me..But
I still wonder if it is possible to solve this without changing the server's culture.